# loop through row copy and paste to another worksheet in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste these rows - one at the time in VBA

```
Name    Col1            Col 2            Col 3
Tom     LTD - 617   LTD - 2236  LTD - 964
David   LTD - 289   LTD - 045   LTD - 055
Peter   LTD - 112   LTD - 687   LTD - 899
```

I need to transpose and paste value for each row in the same column like this

```
Tom
LTD - 617
LTD - 2236
LTD - 964
```

Is there a do loop in VBA that can help me achieve this?

I need the VBA version of how to do this as I'm automating this worksheet, my example is more complex but what I want to do can be illustrated with a simple example like the above. Can anyone suggest a VBA solution - I need to understand how do you loop thorough rows one at the time and outputting them in different location and position.

Answer (score 0):

If your source table is as symmetric as your question suggests and if this is a one-off transformation, I would use formulae to arrange the transposition.  If either of these are untrue, it will be -1 for an inadequate question.

I assume your source table starts in cell A1 and there is nothing to stop me using column F.

Paste the following into cells F2:F5

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW(F2)-2)/4+2,1,4))
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW(F3)-3)/4+2,2,4))
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW(F4)-4)/4+2,3,4))
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW(F5)-5)/4+2,4,4))
```

This will set cell F2:F5 to the values from row 2.  Copy this block of 4 cells (repeat block of 4 cells not cell F5) down as far as necessary.  The values you seek will be in a column as **formulae**.

Use Copy and Paste Special, Values, to get the values you seek as **values**.